# Pycharm Mac, end of statement

Tags: python-3.x

My code worked on my ASUS, but when I tried this in Mac I got an error. Is there an issue with the actual code or maybe a difference in devices?

print(files"{key.strip()} occurs {value} times")

Comment: What error did you got ? Are you using same python version on both machines ?

Comment: The one that worked was in Pipenv using python 3.7 and the one on my mac is Venv python 3

Comment: Sorry, but can you provide the minimal code which some else else can run and what error you see when run on Mac ?